# Breeze expanding child records does not appear to be using correct foreign key

Tags: entity-framework, knockout.js, breeze

So I am using an MVC4 Application Template.  I have defined a very simple code first data model to illustrate my problem.  I am using Breeze to supply my data and I am using Knockout to bind the data to the page.

Here is my Orders Table:

```
public class Order
{
    [Key]
    public long Id { get; set; }
    public string Customer { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("OrderId")]
    public virtual ICollection<Line> Lines { get; set; }
}
```

Here is my Lines Table:

```
public class Line
{
    [Key]
    public long Id { get; set; }
    public long OrderId { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
}
```

I then populate my database as follows:

```
Insert into Orders(Customer) values ('Customer 1');
Insert into Orders(Customer) values ('Customer 2');
Insert into Orders(Customer) values ('Customer 3');
Insert into Lines (OrderId, Description) values (1,'Customer 1 Line 1');
Insert into Lines (OrderId, Description) values (1,'Customer 1 Line 2');
Insert into Lines (OrderId, Description) values (1,'Customer 1 Line 3');
Insert into Lines (OrderId, Description) values (2,'Customer 2 Line 1');
Insert into Lines (OrderId, Description) values (2,'Customer 2 Line 2');
Insert into Lines (OrderId, Description) values (2,'Customer 2 Line 3');
Insert into Lines (OrderId, Description) values (3,'Customer 3 Line 1');
Insert into Lines (OrderId, Description) values (3,'Customer 3 Line 2');
Insert into Lines (OrderId, Description) values (3,'Customer 3 Line 3');
```

So basically every order has 3 detail lines.

Then in my index view I do the following:

```
@section scripts {
<script>
    $(function () {
        var manager = new breeze.EntityManager('breeze/breeze');

        var query = new breeze.EntityQuery()
            .from("Orders").expand("Lines");

        manager.executeQuery(query).then(function (data) {
            ko.applyBindings(data);
        }).fail(function (e) {
            alert(e);
        });
    });
</script>
}
<h2>Orders</h2>

<!-- ko foreach: results -->  
        <br /><label data-bind="text: Customer"></label>      
         <!-- ko foreach: Lines -->                
             <label data-bind="text: Description"></label>                
         <!-- /ko -->
<!-- /ko -->
```

What I would expect to see is something like:

```
Customer 1
Customer 1 Line 1
Customer 1 Line 2
Customer 1 Line 3

Customer 2
Customer 2 Line 1
Customer 2 Line 2
Customer 2 Line 3

Customer 3
Customer 3 Line 1
Customer 3 Line 2
Customer 3 Line 3
```

But instead what I get is:

```
Customer 1  
Customer 1 Line 1

Customer 2   
Customer 1 Line 2

Customer 3   
Customer 1 Line 3
```

So it appears as if it is linking the Order table Id field to the Line table Id field instead of the OrderId field which is the correct foreign key field.

I am not sure if this is a breeze issue, an entity framework issue or a knockout issue.

if I look at the data coming back from Orders Breeze Controller in the chrome developer tools it appears to be sending back the correct data:

```
0: {$id:1, $type:BreezeSample.Order, BreezeSample, Id:1, Customer:Customer 1,…}
$id: "1"
$type: "BreezeSample.Order, BreezeSample"
Customer: "Customer 1"
Id: 1
Lines: [{$id:2, $type:BreezeSample.Line, BreezeSample, Id:1, OrderId:1, Description:Customer 1 Line 1},…]
0: {$id:2, $type:BreezeSample.Line, BreezeSample, Id:1, OrderId:1, Description:Customer 1 Line 1}
1: {$id:3, $type:BreezeSample.Line, BreezeSample, Id:2, OrderId:1, Description:Customer 1 Line 2}
2: {$id:4, $type:BreezeSample.Line, BreezeSample, Id:3, OrderId:1, Description:Customer 1 Line 3}
1: {$id:5, $type:BreezeSample.Order, BreezeSample, Id:2, Customer:Customer 2,…}
$id: "5"
$type: "BreezeSample.Order, BreezeSample"
Customer: "Customer 2"
Id: 2
Lines: [{$id:6, $type:BreezeSample.Line, BreezeSample, Id:4, OrderId:2, Description:Customer 2 Line 1},…]
0: {$id:6, $type:BreezeSample.Line, BreezeSample, Id:4, OrderId:2, Description:Customer 2 Line 1}
1: {$id:7, $type:BreezeSample.Line, BreezeSample, Id:5, OrderId:2, Description:Customer 2 Line 2}
2: {$id:8, $type:BreezeSample.Line, BreezeSample, Id:6, OrderId:2, Description:Customer 2 Line 3}
2: {$id:9, $type:BreezeSample.Order, BreezeSample, Id:3, Customer:Customer 3,…}
$id: "9"
$type: "BreezeSample.Order, BreezeSample"
Customer: "Customer 3"
Id: 3
Lines: [{$id:10, $type:BreezeSample.Line, BreezeSample, Id:7, OrderId:3, Description:Customer 3 Line 1},…]
0: {$id:10, $type:BreezeSample.Line, BreezeSample, Id:7, OrderId:3, Description:Customer 3 Line 1}
1: {$id:11, $type:BreezeSample.Line, BreezeSample, Id:8, OrderId:3, Description:Customer 3 Line 2}
2: {$id:12, $type:BreezeSample.Line, BreezeSample, Id:9, OrderId:3, Description:Customer 3 Line 3}
```

Which all appears correct so I am not sure where the real problem is.

Any help anybody could offer would be appreciated.  Thank You!

Comment: I think your server side model is where the problem is....  You don't have an order navigation property back to the orders

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the EF models that you have shown are why you aren't getting a solid relationship.  You have a collection of Lines but Lines do not have a map back to Order?

```
public class Order
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Customer { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("OrderId")]
    public virtual ICollection<Line> Lines { get; set; }
}
```

Here is my Lines <strike>Table</strike> class:

```
public class Line
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int OrderId { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }

    public virtual Order Order { get; set; }
}
```

Also, you are using long's where I think you mean to use int's

Comment: You are right. That was the problem. I did not realize you need to have a reference back.  I'm just starting out with Entity Framework and Breeze so I really appreciate the assistance. Thank you very much.  Also as for the Long vs Int the company I use to work ran in to an issue where they exceeded the Int datatype in SQL (more than 2.1 billion records) and had to convert to BigInt (i.e. long) and it was a nightmare so ever since I have used primary keys of BigInt to prevent that pain should my tables ever grow to that size in the future.